# Eclipse logcat and graphical layout editor don't show

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got two problems with Eclipse when using it for Android development. The first (and biggest) issue is that the logcat screen on the bottom of the screen stays blank when running an android application. I can however select all the blank lines and save them to file, where I can read the logs. The logs are coming in, but appear to be showed in white font?

Problem two is that the graphical layout editor menu (with all the possible fields you can drag in the editor) only shows when I'm moving my mouse over the different items. It doesn't load right away. This is not a major issue, bit it might have something to do with the first problem.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: **1** In the small left panel of your LogCat Window choose your project name or `All Messages`

Comment: That doesn't work. The messages actually seem to be there. I can select lines and save them to file, from which I can read the text. In the logcat window itself however, the text doesn't display, no matter what font or background colour I choose at Eclipse/Android settings.

Comment: Weird. Never faced this issue (having installed Eclipse more than 10 times on several PCs). What I'd do is: Uninstall and reinstall the ADT Bundle.